# Modelica.Media.R134a Error

Tags: modelica, dymola, fluid-dynamics

In the Modelica Standard Library 3.2.1 a model for the refrigerant R134a was included, but it seems not to work properly with Modelica.Fluid. In a simple example with one `DynamicPipe`, it results in the following error:

```
A calculation of two-phase properties with input of pressure and temperature is not possible.
Please use setState_dTX or setState_phX instead.
The stack of functions is:
setState_pTX_Unique15
setState_pTX_Unique15(101325, 293.15, {1.0}, 0)
```

`use_T_start` is false. What is the problem here? How can it be solved?

TIA

**Update:**

The selected states are h and p, as it should be. The parameters of the pTX call seem to be the default values for the chosen medium.

`PartialStaggeredFlowModel` uses `Medium.density_pTX` and `Medium.setState_pTX`, but changing these to the respective phX-functions does not solve the problem.

Comment: Are you using a pT source maybe? Somewhere in your model a call to `setState_pT` or `density_pT` happens and `Modelica.Media.R134a` just won't work with pT input (take a look at the `setState_pT` function). But where exactly that call happens is hard to say without a full example / copy of your model.

Comment: As I said, the model consists of only one DynamicPipe (and System), without any sources or other additional components.

Comment: Two more ideas, if you are using Dymola: Try the "Used Classes" button or use Simulation setup -> Generate listing of flat Modelica code in .mof file. Then search for `_pT`.

Comment: Or change the assert in the `setState_pT`function to `level=AssertionLevel.warning` and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Especially the hint to "Generate listing of flat Modelica code" was really helpful. As I already suspected in my update, the problem is in `PartialStaggeredFlowModel`.

Comment: also see https://trac.modelica.org/Modelica/ticket/1394

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is already in my update. `PartialStaggeredFlowModel` uses `Medium.density_pTX` and `Medium.setState_pTX`. Replacing these with `Medium.density_phX` and `Medium.setState_phX` avoids the pT-problem. The reason why it did not work at first was one reference to the unmodified class I forgot to change.

Other Modelica.Fluid-components have the same problem, e.g. the pump-models are based on `PartialPump`, which also uses `Medium.density_pTX`.

Thank you for your contributions.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is your choice of thermodynamic states.  As the message indicates, you cannot use a two-phase medium with pressure and temperature as the thermodynamic states.

As a simple example, consider water/ice.  If you measure the temperature as it is freezing, you'll see that when the mixture is "slushy" (contains both liquid and solid), the temperature will remain constant.  So knowing the temperature is not sufficient to know the true (thermodynamic) state of the system because we cannot compute the relative fractions of liquid and solid with that information.  The solution is to use pressure and enthalpy (as the error message suggests) as the thermodynamic states.

I don't know enough about the `Modelica.Media` and `Modelica.Fluid` libraries to tell you how to change your selection of thermodynamic states.  But I suspect you'll find the answer in the documentation of one of those libraries.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I see the thermodynamic problem that the error message suggests, but I don't understand why it happens. When I set the parameter `use_T_start` false, the model should use h instead of T as inital value, but it still seems to call pTX somewhere. With two-phase water, the error does not occur. Any further hints?